How to analytically solve this PDE ? Or what is the ansatz?
$$\partial_t v - \alpha x \partial_x v+ x \partial_y v+ \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\partial_{xx} v = 0$$
This PDE appears in HJB for linear quadratic gaussian control with cross terms of state and control.

Can you share a try? For the ones I've encountered in my class, I think the solutions can be found by separating variables.

I have terminal condition. $$v(T,x,y) = c y^2$$. So, I tried with ansatz $$v(t,x,y) = h(t)y^2$$ which leaves me with $$h'(t) y^2 +2xh(t)y = 0 $$ But I'm not sure if that is right.

This looks suspiciously like the Black-Scholes equation

Yes but with interaction between x and $\partial_y v$

It's possible to solve the PDE
$$
\partial_t v - \alpha x \partial_x v+ x \partial_y v+ \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\partial_{xx} v = 0, \qquad v(T,x,y)=cy^2 \tag{1}
$$
with the ansatz
$$
v(t,x,y)=cy^2+f(t)xy+g(t)x^2+h(t), \tag{2}
$$
where $f, g,$ and $h$ are functions to be determined and satisfying $f(T)=g(T)=h(T)=0.$ Indeed, substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$ we obtain
$$
f'(t)xy+g'(t)x^2+h'(t)-\alpha x[f(t)y+2g(t)x]+x[2cy+f(t)x]+\sigma^2g(t)=0
$$
$$
\implies [f'(t)-\alpha f(t)+2c]xy+[g'(t)-2\alpha g(t)+f(t)]x^2+h'(t)+\sigma^2g(t)=0. \tag{3}
$$
It follows from $(3)$ that $(2)$ is a solution to $(1)$ if
\begin{align}
f'(t)-\alpha f(t)+2c &= 0, \tag{4.1} \\
g'(t)-2\alpha g(t) +f(t) &= 0, \tag{4.2} \\
h'(t)+\sigma^2 g(t)  &= 0. \tag{4.3}
\end{align}
The solution of Eqs. $(4)$ is straightforward; the result is
\begin{align}
f(t)&=\frac{2c}{\alpha}\left[1-e^{\alpha(t-T)}\right], \tag{5.1} \\
g(t)&=\frac{c}{\alpha^2}\left[1-e^{\alpha(t-T)}\right]^2, \tag{5.2} \\
h(t)&=-\frac{c\sigma^2}{\alpha^2}\left\{t-T-\frac{2}{\alpha}\left[e^{\alpha(t-T)}-1\right]+\frac{1}{2\alpha}\left[e^{2\alpha(t-T)}-1\right]\right\}. \tag{5.3}
\end{align}

Why can we conclude the coefficients are 0? @Gonçalo In the case of single-variable polynomial p(x) , if the polynomial is 0 for all values, then all coefficients are 0. But now, we have a polynomial p(x,y), what is the justification from equation (3) to (4)?

The justification is the same: $xy$, $x^2$ and $1$ are linearly independent. But I used a weaker result: if $A=B=C=0$, then $Axy+Bx^2+C=0$.

Im so dumb. Of course, I forgot my Linear Algebra. Thank you @Gonçalo
